# Having issue with chart generation by calling another php script

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts

I am trying to use http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html library to generate piechart. i can create a chart using a static html. like the following

```
<code>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html -->
<html>
<head>

</head> 
<div class="container">


<h1 class="title">Pie Chart</h1>



<div class="chart">
<div id="chart" class="c3" style= "max-height: 280px; position: relative;">
</div>
</div>



</div>
<script src="./js2/d3-3.5.0.min-3b564392.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js2/c3.min-3c814909.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--
<script src="./js2/chart_pie-bdaca3a4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    }
});


setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ["Series1", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
            ["series2", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
            ["series3", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8],
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data2'
    });
}, 2500);
</script>


</body></html>
</code>
```

now, i split the chart block into another php file . my intention is to generate and poulate the data for the chart from that file. however now chart goes not get drawn. no clue why its doing when split the code. any help are much appreciated.

now my code looks like this.

main html file

"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html -->
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function showUserAssignment(str)
     {

     if (str=="")
       {
       document.getElementById("compainsummaryReport").innerHTML="";
       return;
       }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
         document.getElementById("compainsummaryReport").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","generatechart.php?projectname="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     }
     </script>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="container">

<form action="index.htm#">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select a  CAMPAIGN</label>
        <select name="campaign" onchange="showUserAssignment(this.value)" data-placeholder="Choose a Campaign" class="chosen-select mb-15" tabindex="2">
          <option value="test">test</option>
          <option value="test2">test2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<h1 class="title">Pie Chart</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div id="compainsummaryReport"></div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

"

and generatechart.php file as follows

"

```
<div class="chart">
  <div id="chart" class="c3" style= "max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
</div>

<script src="./js2/d3-3.5.0.min-3b564392.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js2/c3.min-3c814909.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--
<script src="./js2/chart_pie-bdaca3a4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    }
});


setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ["Series1", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
            ["series2", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
            ["series3", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8],
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data2'
    });
}, 2500);
</script>
```

"

Any help are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see in your code where you're loading your data from your php into the javascript.

I think the best way to handle this is to create a json that your php script will return. For details to JSON encoding in PHP please have a look at this [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm). Then you can easily load it with `d3.json(...)`.

The delay inside of the `success` callback is only to have the first data bit longer displayed.

See demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/83yygdy1/).

```js
 var chart = c3.generate({
     data: {
         // iris data from R
         columns: [
             ['data1', 30],
             ['data2', 120], ],
         type: 'pie',
         onclick: function (d, i) {
             console.log("onclick", d, i);
         },
         onmouseover: function (d, i) {
             console.log("onmouseover", d, i);
         },
         onmouseout: function (d, i) {
             console.log("onmouseout", d, i);
         }
     }
 });
             
 d3.json('http://www.mocky.io/v2/54e8ff18ea18fba50709d59b', function (error, data) {
     console.log(error, data);
     console.log('loaded json, now add to chart after a short delay');
     setTimeout(function () {
         chart.load(data);
     }, 1000);
 });
 /*
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ["Series1", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
            ["series2", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
            ["series3", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8],
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data2'
    });
}, 2500);*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
    <div id="chart" class="c3" style="max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
</div>
```